# Multiple slashes in database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, forms

I have a wordpress based site with an html form that saves data in mysql database through json. I did it in a way like this:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$db = $wpdb->prefix . 'db_table';
$json_query = $wpdb->get_row(
    "
    SELECT app, ts
    FROM $db
    WHERE user_id = $user_id
    ",
    ARRAY_A
);
$json = json_decode($json_query[app], true);
?>

<label>Family Name</label>
<input type="text" name="json[family_name]" <?php echo ($json_ok[family_name] ? 'value="' . $json_ok[family_name] . '"' : ''); ?> />

<?php
$json_send = json_encode( $_POST['json'] );

if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $wpdb->update(
        $db,
        array(
            'app'   =>  $json_send
        ),
        array( 'user_id' => $user_id )
    );
?>
```

It works but if user insert the apostrophe character the sistem save apostrophe preceded by a backslash. Every time user saves, the sistem add a backslash. Now I have the database full of backslashes like this:

```
{"family_name":"Rossi","indirizzo":"strada d\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'oro","first_name":"Maurizio","country_birth":"Italy","city_birth":"Roma"}
```

How can i solve this?
Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't store all of this data to a single column, you should store all the data to their own column.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton where is he storing all of this in a single column? He's not shown you any schema or database structure, so that's an assumption. I believe this is a wordpress site and he's using Wordpress' built in db wrapper to update items in the database, which will match data to columns. Most likely the update function will be calling `addslashes()` in the php code. The solution would be to strip out the slashes anywhere it's selected from the database to avoid the recursion.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton this is using Wordpress though, so not vanilla php functions. Most likely the function parses a JSON object and matches them to the defined table.

Comment: @JohnBell I'm not a big fan of WordPress, nor do I use it or any of its functions - but if a WordPress function is designed to parse a JSON string instead of the built-in array then there are 2 things to say; the designer of the function put in way more effort than required, and they shouldn't have done it that way.

Comment: I saved the whole form in a single column via the json because I did not know how many fields of the form I would have had. In addition, adding them to the json instead of the table seemed easier.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton nobody is a fan of WordPress ;) It does seem he is saving them in a single column anyway. Not good practice!

Comment: @FoscoVentura It may be easier _at the time_, but following good practice, it is never a good idea to do it that way. It makes using the data harder later, or searching the table data, and it causes issues like the one you are having. I recommend completely redoing your table structure to support all of the columns you need instead of saving all the data to a single column. You can always add more columns later.

Comment: Ok, i will redoing all later, now I need to work on the database that have more than 500 user records. I'm going to try str_replace solution.
How can I convert old records in the new multiple-column structure?

Answer (score 2):

I have dealt with the same issue myself when saving and using json encoded stings in wordpress. This is what solved it for me.

Just make a call to stripslashes() when displaying value in input;

like so:

```
<input type="text" name="json[family_name]" <?php echo (stripslashes($json_ok[family_name]) ? 'value="' . stripslashes($json_ok[family_name]) . '"' : ''); ?> />
```

When it gets saved again it will stop adding those extra slashes. As mentioned in the comment by [John Bell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1667945/john-bell) when you make a call to the update function it is calling addslashes().

Comment: So basically more or less exactly the same answer I posted 12 minutes before you then...

Comment: you did not call stripslashes

Comment: @JohnBell I would say this is a slightly better solution, because stripslashes would work better than str_replace.

Comment: xD I called the PHP that does the same as stripslashes. Pedantic lol.

Comment: @JohnBell Well judging purely from a syntax standpoint, it's much easier to understand what stripslashes is doing (For a non-seasoned programmer). Not to mention it is shorter.

Comment: You'd need to handle the slash left over later on though depending on how he's displaying it. From a non-seasoned programmer standpoint that could possibly be another trip to SO. Best to remove all the slashes.